# Creating a new Database on Azure with C#

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

Is that any way to create a new Database on a Azure connection with a SqlCommand?

Now, i have this:

```
 String str = $"Create database {DatabaseName} ( EDITION = 'basic' );";
 SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);

 var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Config.ConnectionString(DatabaseName));
 try
 {
      myConn.Open();
      myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

The connection is made successfully but the `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` is raising : A connection time out.

I need to make Databases from my .NET Core application with a randomly generated name on the azure. Is that possible?

Comment: you try to execute your statement against a database, which does not exist yet. You need to execute the create database statement against the `master` database

Comment: I think you are trying to create new SQL database Service by code?

Comment: see here for a similar example. Just exchange the Create Database statement and the connection string: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/307283/how-to-create-a-sql-server-database-programmatically-by-using-ado-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create new database in Azure SQL Database. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current

Just use a usual create database statement (against the `master` database):

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB2
( EDITION = 'GeneralPurpose' );
```

You might need to increase your timeout, though. The statement took about 40 seconds when I just tested it.